# Binary Search giving incorrect output

Tags: java, binary-search

For the input binarySearch(2, A, 9), where A = {2,6,7,7,11,15,25,37,45}, the program is giving the output "Not Present", when it should give "Present".
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
String binarySearch(int x, int[] A, int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return ("Not present");
    else
    {
        int mid = n/2;
        if(x==A[mid])
            return ("Present");
        else if (x<A[mid])
            binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,0,mid),mid);
        else
            binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,mid,n),n-mid);

        return ("Not present");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your last line returns `Not present` no matter what recursive calls return.

Comment: Use curly brackets and you wont have mistakes like this.

Comment: Just realized. Seems like such a silly question now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Missing `return` statement in the recursive call:

```
else if (x<A[mid])
    return binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,0,mid),mid);
else
    return binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,mid,n),n-mid);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the recursive call

```
  String binarySearch(int x, int[] A, int n)
   {
        if(n==0)
           return ("Not present");
        else
           {
             int mid = n/2;
             if(x==A[mid])
                 return ("Present");
              else if (x<A[mid])
                  return  binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,0,mid),mid);
               else
                  return binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,mid,n),n-mid);


       }
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your forgot to add `return`  statement along with the `else if` recursion calls 
because now it will just return the `Present` only if `x` is found at middle , rest of the calls works but won't return anything ,so it should be

```
static String binarySearch(int x, int[] A, int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return ("Not present");
    else
    {
        int mid = n/2;
        if(x==A[mid])
            return ("Present");
        else if (x<A[mid])
            return binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,0,mid),mid);
        else
            return binarySearch(x, Arrays.copyOfRange(A,mid,n),n-mid);

    }
}
```